# How to fix dynamic code evaluation issue in fortify scan because of using eval() in java script

Tags: javascript

HP fortify scan shows a dynamic code evaluation issue shows as below.It says eval() function in javascript leads to security issue. How fix this security issue.
 Below given is the code.

```
        if (objItem.column == 'leftColumn')
        {
            strItems = lcItems.value
        }
        else if (objItem.column == 'rightColumn')
        {
            strItems = rcItems.value;
        }
        else if (objItem.column == 'toolbox')
        {
            strItems = tbItems.value;
        }
        objItems = eval(strItems);
        item = null;
```

Here eval(strItems); is code for security violation. How fix this issue. see the issue details and recommendations to fix issue
[Issue explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bEet.png)

[Reccomendation to fix issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Hlc.png)

Comment: Without seeing *what* you're running through `eval`, it's not possible to tell you how to rewrite it without `eval` (or whether or not you can safely ignore the warnings, in the remote possibility that use of `eval` is actually necessary here).

Comment: What is the code tryping to do? e.g. what does the `strItems` variable evaluate to?  Once we know that, we can provide a better solution for you.

Comment: document.getElementById(tbItemsID);

Comment: Are you saying that the value of `strItems` is actually `"document.getElementById(tbItemsID);"`?  If so, I would modify it to only be the **ID** that you care about, and then do the lookup by ID instead of the eval statement.

Comment: If all you want to do is avoid the warning, you could try `(0, eval)(strItems)`. But it would be **much** better to rewrite the code without `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what the `strItems` variable you are using evaluates to (e.g. how is it being used?)

If the value is the ID of another element, then changing the eval line to this would work:

```
objItems = document.getElementById(strItems);
```

However if it is the name of an element...

```
//presuming there is at least 1 match by name, drop the index if you want the "set"
objItems = document.getElementsByName(strItems)[0];
```

or something else? you'll need to change the code accordingly.